# Select name in autocomplete text box then load mobile no in 2nd text box

Tags: c#

There are two fields in my database table: `name` and `mobile no`, and two textboxes in a form. My first textbox is an AutoComplete textBox by fetching name from database. I want it so that when I select `name` in the text box then load `mobile no` in second text box. Can some one help this?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoComplete();
}
public void AutoComplete()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Database Source.....");
    conn.Open();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection AutoItem = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from table1", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(tbl);
    foreach (DataRow rw in tbl.Rows)
    {
        AutoItem.Add(rw["name"].ToString());
    }
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutoItem;
}
```

Comment: ok, you want to do something on select, but all you show here is the initialization code.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire some event after the text selection, such give a button like `Get Mobile No` and on click event of that button fetch the mobile no using the name